# How to implement a mailing system with Rails that sends emails in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I want to implement a reliable mailing system with Ruby on Rails that sends emails in the background as sending email sometimes takes like 10 seconds or more so I don't want the user to wait. Some ideas I thought of:

1. Write to a table in DB a have a
   background process that go over and
   send email (concern: potential many
   reads/writes to DB slows down my
   application)
2. Messaging Queue
   background process / Rake task
   (concern: if server crashes queued
   mails will be lost also might eat up
   a lot of memory if many emails)

I was wondering if you a know of a good solution that provides a balance between reliability and performance.

Answer (score 3):

I think Starling and Workling will be able to assist you =) Watch this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the feature or rely on external services.

I have been using [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/) for the last 2 months and I'm really happy with it.
An other solution is [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/).

Otherwise, if you want to code it, first you need a queue system.
For Rails, you can use [DelayedJob](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Resque](http://github.com/defunkt/resque). Sending emails in the background is probably the most simple solution, the "problem" is dealing with failures and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the mail-queue plugin?

http://code.google.com/p/mail-queue/

The docs seem to suggest it stores the mails in a DB table, thus avoiding #2 at least.