# Do I run a background job for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, background-process

Hi I send out an email every time that someone follows another person in my web app. This significantly slows response time down because the ajax isn't rendered until the email is sent through the mailer. Is this a case where I use a background job? I'm unfamiliar with the use case for background jobs and am wondering, if this is the scenario to use it in, where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfect scenario for background jobs. Some general gems for background jobs would be

- [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)
- [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque)

More options in this question: [How to implement a mailing system with Rails that sends emails in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665920/how-to-implement-a-mailing-system-with-rails-that-sends-emails-in-the-background)

Comment: I'm currently running on a heroku server that's free, is there a way to run jobs without having to upgrade?